# Find all possible phrase matches between string and lookup table

Tags: r, keyword-search, udpipe

I have a data frame with a bunch of text strings. In a second data frame I have a list of phrases that I'm using as a lookup table. I want to search the text strings for all possible phrase matches in the lookup table.

My problem is that some of the phrases have overlapping words. For example: "eggs" and "green eggs".

```
library(udpipe)
library(dplyr)

# Download english dictionary
ud_model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(ud_model$file_model)

# Create example data
sample <- data.frame(doc_id = 1, text = "the cat in the hat ate green eggs and ham")
phrases <- data.frame(phrase = c("cat", "hat", "eggs", "green eggs", "ham", "the cat"))

# Tokenize text
x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model, x = sample$text, doc_id = sample$doc_id)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$token <- tolower(x$token)

test_results <- x %>% select(doc_id, token)
test_results$term <- txt_recode_ngram(test_results$token, 
                                 compound = phrases$phrase, 
                                 ngram = str_count(phrases$phrase, '\\w+'), 
                                 sep = " ")

# Remove any tokens that don't match a phrase in the lookup table
test_results <- filter(test_results, term %in% phrases$phrase)
```

In the results you can see that "the cat" is returned but not "cat", "green eggs" but not "eggs".

```
> test_results$term
[1] "the cat"    "hat"        "green eggs" "ham"
```

How can I find all possible phrase matches between a text string and a lookup table?

I should add that I'm not wedded to any particular package. I'm just using udpipe here because I'm most familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use `grepl` to match if a string is inside another one. From that you `apply` `grepl` to all other matching patterns

```
# Create example data
sample <- data.frame(doc_id = 1, text = "the cat in the hat ate green eggs and ham")
phrases <- data.frame(phrase = c("cat", "hat", "eggs", "green eggs", "ham", "the cat"))

apply(phrases, 1, grepl,sample$text)
```

And if you want your matches you can just :

```
phrases[apply(phrases, 1, grepl,sample$text),]
```

But maybe a `dataframe` type is not the most relevant for phrases